# Delphi XE2 Data Module expects only database components?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, datamodule

In prior versions of Delphi, I have used the data module (`TDataModule`) as a place to keep non-visual components to avoid cluttering up the main form. In Delphi XE2, when I create a new data module, it only allows me to place database related components in it (such as `TADOConnection` and `TDataSource`). Why is this and how can I put other components in it? Is there an alternative?

Comment: Can you give an example of a non-visual component (one that is provided with Delphi, preferably) that it won't allow? I've never seen this problem.

Comment: Like a `TImageList` or `TMainMenu` or `TActionManager` - When I try to paste one, it says the component class is not found, and the palette only shows database related components.

Comment: Could it be my specific edition of RAD Studio? But then I have Enterprise, should have about everything.

Comment: I can confirm this with `File->New->VCL Forms Application`, and then `File->New->Other->Delphi Files->Datamodule`, which leaves only the database, Intraweb, FastReports, and Indy components available in the component palette. (TImageList and TActionList are not there.) Using the Pro SKU, so it's not that causing the problem.

Comment: Interesting, strange why this limitation would exist in the first place. The company's not ready to upgrade to XE3 quite yet, we're still settling into XE2.

Comment: @JerryDodge can you switch to datamodule -> F6 -> type component name -> RETURN? this is weird, never had this...

Comment: @Ken In fact it wasn't broken in XE2. And XE3 didn't fix anything. What XE3 did was move actions out of the VCL and into a lower level and so be available to all frameworks.

Comment: @David: Thanks. I was obviously wrong. :-)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Data modules changed with the XE2 release. Remember that XE2 introduced a new component framework, FireMonkey, in addition to the long-standing VCL. A new pseudo-property, named [`ClassGroup`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE2/en/ClassGroup_pseudo-property_of_TDataModule) was added to data modules. This controls what components can be added to the data module in the IDE designer.

The default [`ClassGroup`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE2/en/ClassGroup_pseudo-property_of_TDataModule) for a data module is `System.Classes.TPersistent`. This specifies that the data module is framework neutral and so accepts neither VCL components nor FMX components.

In your case you probably want to accept VCL components so you need to specify a `ClassGroup` of `Vcl.Controls.TControl`.

Read all about `ClassGroup` in the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE2/en/ClassGroup_pseudo-property_of_TDataModule).

> System.Classes.TDataModule and its descendant classes, such as
>   Web.HTTPApp.TWebModule, have a pseudo-property named ClassGroup that
>   does the following:
>
> - Determines the framework affinity for the data module. That is, ClassGroup specifies that the data module is either framework-neutral
>     or is to work with a specific framework (namely, VCL or FMX).
> - Enables framework-specific nonvisual components in the Tool Palette. You need to set a framework-specific value for ClassGroup in
>     the Object Inspector in order to enable framework-specific nonvisual
>     components such as the following:
>
>   - TActionList is VCL-only, and so to enable TActionList in the Tool Palette, you must set ClassGroup to the VCL setting.
>   - TTimer exists in both FMX and VCL. To enable TTimer for the correct framework, you must set ClassGroup to either FMX or VCL, to
>       match the framework of the parent application. (TTimer and TActionList
>       are further discussed later in this topic.)

Answer (score 11):

This (buggy) behavior in

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes;

type
  TDataModule2 = class(TDataModule)
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;

var
  DataModule2: TDataModule2;

implementation

{%CLASSGROUP 'System.Classes.TPersistent'}

{$R *.dfm}

end.
```

is caused by the line

```
{%CLASSGROUP 'System.Classes.TPersistent'}
```

To get rid of just delete or modify the line into

```
{.%CLASSGROUP 'System.Classes.TPersistent'}
```

After switch to `Design` View you will see all the components as you expect.

(Delphi XE2 16.0.4504.48759)

Comment: Perfecto! I knew it had to be something simple, as always.

Comment: PS - The hard part was figuring out how to create the data module in a way that it could be used throughout the app with common components - I wound up creating/destroying it in a try..finally block in the project's main `dpr` file, wrapping the form creation and `Run`.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11250019/what-does-tdatamodule-classgroup-pseudo-property-in-delphi-xe2-really-do

Comment: We have no problems in an app that was *migrated* from D2007 to XE2 (TImageList, TcxSchedulerStorage etc), but its good to know this when we add another data module.

Comment: You can do this right inside the Object Inspector: select the datamodule and set its ClassGroup property accordingly. Then close and reopen the damodule unit.

Comment: There's nothing buggy here. And the right solution for Jerry is to set the ClassGroup to VCL.

Comment: Now that it's solved, I'm pondering why would `TPersistent` make the data module only allow database related components? How does that work? A `TComponent` is a `TPersistent`.

Comment: It doesn't just allow database controls. It blocks VCL and FMX components. In XE3 actions are allowed because they are no longer VCL specific. And as for TPersistent. It's just a name. Thr docs make it clear what it means.