# When does a ShortCut fire?

Tags: delphi, keyboard-shortcuts, vcl

Yesterday I discovered a situation wherein a keyboard ShortCut did not fire when I was expecting it to.

The specific situation was: I pressed the ShortCut key combination for an Action of an ActionList on an MDI child, while a side bar on the MDI form was focussed.

I always was under the impression that ShortCuts would work globally. In exactly which circumstances do or do they not fire?

Comment: Can you be precise as to what a sidebar is?

Comment: @David [Something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7266319/757830).

Comment: I guess what counts is where it lives in the mdi form.

Comment: According to the answer the shortcut should have been fired as per the accepted answer given that the active form had a ActionList, unless of course the action was disabled somehow. Was that the case?

Comment: @costa The MDI child form wasn't active, the MDI main form was.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

That's a deceptively simple question with a surprisingly long answer. First I will deal with some basics and then follow the ShortCut through the VCL code to finally arrive at - I hope - a satisfying conclusion.

#### What is a ShortCut?

A ShortCut represents a special keyboard combination of one or more keys that cause an operation. *Special* means special to the programmer who gives meaning to the specific key combination.

In Delphi a ShortCut is of type `TShortCut` which is declared as a whole number within the `Word` range (0..65535). A ShortCut is often constructed out of several keys, e.g.:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> = `scCtrl` + `Ord('K')` = `16384` + `75` = `16459`.

#### How to specify a ShortCut?

ShortCuts can be assigned to the `ShortCut` or `SecondaryShortCuts` property of an Action or to the `ShortCut` property of a MenuItem, thus invoking that Action's `OnExecute` event or MenuItem's `OnClick` event when the ShortCut's keyboard combination is pressed.

For an Action's ShortCut to be processed, it is required that the Action is enabled, and added to a not suspended ActionList or attached to an enabled MenuItem. Likewise, for a MenuItem's ShortCut to be processed, it is required that the MenuItem is added to a Menu.

ShortCuts can also be interpreted from the [Application](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.OnShortCut)'s, a [Form](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.OnShortCut)'s or from an [ApplicationEvents](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.AppEvnts.TCustomApplicationEvents.OnShortCut)' `OnShortCut` event. Within those events, the `Msg` parameter holds the keycode in its `CharCode` member, and possibly special keys like <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> can be extracted using [`GetKeyState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646301(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
procedure TForm1.FormShortCut(var Msg: TWMKey; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  if (Msg.CharCode = Ord('K')) and (GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL) < 0) then
  begin
    Caption := 'CTRL+K pressed';
    Handled := True;
  end;
end;
```

If the `Handled` parameter is set to `True`, any subsequent processing for the key will be skipped.

#### How is a ShortCut catched?

The VCL does not keep a list of all specified ShortCuts. (How could it?). Thus *all* keystrokes could potentially be a ShortCut. And that is exactly how the VCL interprets ShortCuts: by evaluating every key that is pressed.

Peter Below wrote an excellent and comprehensive article dealing with [A Key's Odyssey](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/38447) through the VCL. In short, a ShortCut is catched as follows:

- `TApplication.Run` picks up every Windows message send to the application,
- `TApplication.ProcessMessage` calls `IsKeyMsg` which passes the message - if a `WM_KEYDOWN` message - on to the `CN_KEYDOWN` message handler of the **focussed Control**.

#### How is the ShortCut processed?

`TWinControl.CNKeyDown` examines whether the key is a menu key (we'll see the definition of this *menu* is beyond a physical Menu):

- [`TWinControl.IsMenuKey`](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/38447#16ShortcuthandlingintheVCLIntoTWinControlIsMenuKey) first examines whether the key is a ShortCut within the Control's or one of its parent's **PopupMenu**,

  - [`TMenu.IsShortCut`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.Menus.TMenu.IsShortCut) <sup>1)</sup> traverses *all* its (sub)menu items and calls the `OnClick` event handler of the enabled MenuItem with the ShortCut, if any,
- If not processed, it examines whether the key is a ShortCut of the Form on which the Control resides by calling [`TCustomForm.IsShortCut`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.IsShortCut) <sup>2)</sup>,

  - The **[`OnShortCut`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.OnShortCut) event of the Form** is called, if assigned,
  - If not processed, it examines whether the key is a ShortCut within the **Form's MainMenu** (see <sup>1)</sup>), if any,
  - If not processed, it dispatches the key to all **ActionLists owned by the Form** (still talking about the active Form). Prior to Delphi version 10 (BDS2006), these ActionLists need to be directly owned by the Form and were kept in a protected (which made intervention possible when needed) field `FActionLists`. [That was considered a bug](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=7879) and as from BDS2006, the field was eliminated and the ActionLists could be indirectly owned by the Form too.

    - [`TCustomActionList.IsShortCut`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.ActnList.TCustomActionList.IsShortCut) traverses all its Actions and calls `HandleShortCut` of the enabled Action with the ShortCut set in its `ShortCut` or `SecondaryShortCuts` property, if any,
- If not processed, [`Application.IsShortCut`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.IsShortCut) is called (via `CM_APPKEYDOWN`),

  - The **[`OnShortCut`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.OnShortCut) event of the Application** is fired, this includes [`OnShortCut`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.AppEvnts.TCustomApplicationEvents.OnShortCut) events of all ApplicationEvents components within the project, if any assigned,
  - If not processed, it calls the `IsShortCut` routine of the **MainForm** (see <sup>2)</sup>), but *only when the MainForm is enabled*. E.g. when the active Form is a modal Form, then the MainForm will be disabled. This will fire the **`OnShortCut` event of the MainForm** or will traverse all directly or indirectly owned **ActionLists of the MainForm** (depending on Delphi version as mentioned above).

#### So, when is the ShortCut processed?

When it is:

- Set for an enabled MenuItem in a PopupMenu which is attached to the currently focussed Control or to any of its parents,
- Set for an enabled MenuItem in a MainMenu which is shown on the currently active Form or on the MainForm, but only when the MainForm is enabled,
- Set for an enabled Action in a not suspended ActionList which is owned by the currently active Form or by the MainForm, but only when the MainForm is enabled,
- Catched in the `OnShortCut` event of the currently active Form or of the MainForm, but only when the MainForm is enabled,
- Catched in the `OnShortCut` event of the Applicaton or any ApplicationEvents components.

#### And when is the ShortCut not processed?

When it is set for:

- A disabled MenuItem,
- A MenuItem without Menu,
- A MenuItem in a MainMenu that is not attached to a Form,
- A MenuItem in a PopupMenu that is attached to a sibling,
- A disabled Action,
- An Action without ActionList,
- An Action in an ActionList that is not owned by the currently active Form or the MainForm. E.g.: another Form, a DataModule, Application, a utilities unit, etc...
- An Action in an ActionList that is not directly owned by the currently active Form or the MainForm in Delphi versions below BDS2006.

Comment: Thanks for the very well written summary - I know Peter's article is comprehensive, but you can easily lost in that article ;)

Comment: So after reading your answer, I checked `TCustomForm.IsShortCut`, it seems that even if, for example, `FormChild` is parented/nested in `FormParent`  but if it's not owned by `FormParent`, shortcuts in `FormChild` won't be processed if it's not currently focused?

Comment: Yes, after experiments, I confirm the answer is yes for my above comment.