# Is there a way to have a KeyPreview-like functionality when working with Frames?

Tags: delphi, c++builder, vcl, tframe, keypreview

I would like to have a KeyPreview functionality within Frames, I mean, that when the input (say, one of the controls of the frame is selected, or the mouse is inside) is in a frame (which would have several panels and other controls) then the keys pressed by the user are first processed by the frame.

Is there a way to do this? I haven't found a property similar to KeyPreview in TFrame.

I'm using version XE5 of RAD Studio, altough I mostly work with C++Builder.

Comment: @TLama there is no KeyDown event for the TFrame

Comment: I meant overriding `KeyDown` method, but that doesn't seem to work hence I've deleted my comment.

Comment: Let me know when you find out! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27116331/handle-gestures-when-initiated-from-a-frame (slightly different subject, but still about how frames "swallow" user events)

Comment: Can't you do this from Application.OnMessage?

Comment: You could drop a `TApplicationEvents` on the Frame and handle the `OnMessage` event (processing `WM_KEYDOWN` message).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to my recent ["When does a ShortCut fire"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27083261/757830)-investigation, I have worked out a stand alone solution for your Frame.

In short: all key messages enter in `TWinControl.CNKeyDwon` of the active control. That method calls `TWinControl.IsMenuKey` which traverses **all parents** while determining whether the message is a ShortCut. Is does so by calling its `GetPopupMenu.IsShortCut` method. I have overridden the Frame's `GetPopupMenu` method by creating one if it is not present. Note that at all time you still can add a PopupMenu to the Frame yourself. By subclassing `TPopupMenu` and overriding the `IsShortCut` method, the Frame's `KeyDown` method is called, which serves as the KeyPreview functionality you require. (I could also have assigned the OnKeyDdown event handler).

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Messages, System.Classes, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Menus,
  Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TPopupMenu = class(Vcl.Menus.TPopupMenu)
  public
    function IsShortCut(var Message: TWMKey): Boolean; override;
  end;

  TFrame2 = class(TFrame)
    Label1: TLabel;
    Edit1: TEdit;
  private
    FPreviewPopup: TPopupMenu;
  protected
    function GetPopupMenu: Vcl.Menus.TPopupMenu; override;
    procedure KeyDown(var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState); override;
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TPopupMenu }

function TPopupMenu.IsShortCut(var Message: TWMKey): Boolean;
var
  ShiftState: TShiftState;
begin
  ShiftState := KeyDataToShiftState(Message.KeyData);
  TFrame2(Owner).KeyDown(Message.CharCode, ShiftState);
  Result := Message.CharCode = 0;
  if not Result then
    Result := inherited IsShortCut(Message);
end;

{ TFrame2 }

function TFrame2.GetPopupMenu: Vcl.Menus.TPopupMenu;
begin
  Result := inherited GetPopUpMenu;
  if Result = nil then
  begin
    if FPreviewPopup = nil then
      FPreviewPopup := TPopupMenu.Create(Self);
    Result := FPreviewPopup;
  end;
end;

procedure TFrame2.KeyDown(var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if (Key = Ord('X')) and (ssCtrl in Shift) then
  begin
    Label1.Caption := 'OH NO, DON''T DO THAT!';
    Key := 0;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: There is a downside: `TranslateMessage` isn't called yet, so all characters are capital. How do I fix that?

Comment: This looks nice! I will try it tomorrow and let you know. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: This solves my need just fine, thanks!

I don't have a problem with the characters being capital, as I'm only handling special keys.

Comment: @NGLN This seems dirty and convoluted. Why bring menus in here?

Comment: @David Indeed, it is a strange workaround to get from an active control to the parent Frame, but it (kinda) works and it is a solution. That's why.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just hook the message loop in the normal way with an OnMessage handler?

Answer (score 2):

If you only have one frame on the form at the time you could make use of forms KeyPreview ability and forward the necessary information to the frame.

If you are only forwarding the information you don't need to make any changes to original VCL code just make a modified TFrame class. So there is no wory that you might break whole VCL doing it.

Here is a quick code example:

MainForm code:

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Unit3, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    ModifiedFrame: TModifiedFrame;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    procedure FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //This is required since I'm asigning frames OnKeyDown event method manually
  ModifiedFrame.OnKeyDown := ModifiedFrame.FrameKeyDown;
end;

procedure TForm2.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  //Forward key down information to ModifiedFrame
  ModifiedFrame.DoKeyDown(Sender, Key, Shift);
  if Key = 0 then
    MessageDlg('Key was handled by the modified frame!',mtInformation,[mbOK],0)
  else
    MessageDlg('Key was not handled!',mtInformation,[mbOK],0);
end;

end.
```

ModifiedFrame code:

```
unit Unit3;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes,
  Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TModifiedFrame = class(TFrame)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    //Normally this method would be added by the Delphi IDE when you set the
    //OnKeyDown event but here I created this manually in order to avoid crating
    //design package with modified frame
    procedure FrameKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FOnKeyDown: TKeyEvent;
  public
    { Public declarations }
    //This is used to recieve forwarded key down information from the Form
    procedure DoKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
  published
    //Property to alow setting the OnKeyDown event at design-time
    //NOTE: In order for this to work properly you have to put this modified
    //frame class into separate unti and register it as new design time component
    property OnKeyDown: TKeyEvent read FOnKeyDown write FOnKeyDown;
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TModifiedFrame.DoKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  //Check to see if OnKeyDownEvent has been assigned. If it is foward the key down
  //information to the event procedure
  if Assigned(FOnKeyDown) then FOnKeyDown(Self, Key, Shift);
end;

procedure TModifiedFrame.FrameKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  //Do something
  if Key = VK_RETURN then
  begin
    MessageBeep(0);
    Key := 0;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Using simillar approach you can forward other key events.

Comment: Yes, I have something similar in place but was looking for something more elegant :)

Comment: More elegant? How do you mean more elegant?

Comment: Well, something that didn't involve changing each of the forms where the frames are  used, mostly.

Answer (score 0):

It is doable, if you are willing to change VCL code.

KeyPreview is handled in `TWinControl.DoKeyDown` method. As it can be seen from the code control that has focus will lookup its parent form and invoke its `DoKeyDown` method if `KeyPreview` is turned on.

```
function TWinControl.DoKeyDown(var Message: TWMKey): Boolean;
var
  ShiftState: TShiftState;
  Form, FormParent: TCustomForm;
  LCharCode: Word;
begin
  Result := True;

 // Insert modification here

  { First give the immediate parent form a try at the Message }
  Form := GetParentForm(Self, False);
  if (Form <> nil) and (Form <> Self) then
  begin
    if Form.KeyPreview and TWinControl(Form).DoKeyDown(Message) then
      Exit;
    { If that didn't work, see if that Form has a parent (ie: it is docked) }
    if Form.Parent <> nil then
    begin
      FormParent := GetParentForm(Form);
      if (FormParent <> nil) and (FormParent <> Form) and
      FormParent.KeyPreview and TWinControl(FormParent).DoKeyDown(Message) then
        Exit;
    end;
  end;
  with Message do
  begin
    ShiftState := KeyDataToShiftState(KeyData);
    if not (csNoStdEvents in ControlStyle) then
    begin
      LCharCode := CharCode;
      KeyDown(LCharCode, ShiftState);
      CharCode := LCharCode;
      if LCharCode = 0 then Exit;
    end;
  end;
  Result := False;
end;
```

To change that behavior, you would need to either change `TWinControl.DoKeyDown` code to scan for frames too or intercept `WM_KEYDOWN` and `WM_SYSKEYDOWN` for every `TWinControl` descendant you want to use, and finally add `KeyPreview` field to base Frame class.

Probably best option would be to declare `IKeyPreview` interface and when scanning for parent forms/frames test if parent implements that interface. If none found, you can fall back to original code. That would contain VCL code changes only to `TWinControl.DoKeyDown` method, and you can easily implement interface in Frames where needed.

**Note:** On Windows control that has focus receives key events. So above modifications would be able to find frame only if some of its controls has focus. Whether or not mouse would be over the frame or not would not have any influence on functionality.

More detailed code would look like this:

Interface definition that Frame would have to implement:

```
  IKeyPreview = interface
    ['{D7318B16-04FF-43BE-8E99-6BE8663827EE}']
    function GetKeyPreview: boolean;
    property KeyPreview: boolean read GetKeyPreview;
  end;
```

Function for finding parent frame that implements `IKeyPreview` interface, should be put somewhere in `Vcl.Controls` implementation section:

```
function GetParentKeyPreview(Control: TWinControl): IKeyPreview;
var
  Parent: TWinControl;
begin
  Result := nil;
  Parent := Control.Parent;
  while Assigned(Parent) do
    begin
      if Parent is TCustomForm then Parent := nil
      else
      if Supports(Parent, IKeyPreview, Result) then Parent := nil
      else Parent := Parent.Parent;
    end;
end;
```

`TWinControl.DoKeyDown` modification (insert in above original code):

```
var
  PreviewParent: IKeyPreview;

  PreviewParent := GetParentKeyPreview(Self);
  if PreviewParent <> nil then
    begin
      if PreviewParent.KeyPreview and TWinControl(PreviewParent).DoKeyDown(Message) then
        Exit;
    end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea and the detailed code, DAlija, but I fear it's not really an option in this case to modify the VCL library. If in Delphi I would think twice before doing so, with C++Builder I just get shivers. I wonder why Embarcadero hasn't added a way to do this out of the box, as for what I can find, it's a somewhat recurring issue. I understand the problems it might cause, but so does several other things you can do.

Comment: Since modifications are only in implementation part, that should not be so problematic, but I do understand your reluctance. I am not big fan of changing VCL code either.

Comment: Yeah, enough issues I have with a non-working debugger and crashing IDE, and having to mantain changes to several third party libraries for them to work with C++Builder, to worry about breaking something so low level :/ Thanks anyway!! I think I will go the ugly route of adding a Key handler to the Frame and calling it from the forms where the frame is used.

Comment: Err, unless my spectacles fail me (and they frequently do), the OP gives no indication of Delphi version.  BC finds no less than 1649 sections differing between Controls.Pas in D7 and XE6 and 19 changed lines in TWinControl.DoKeyDown alone between the two.  So I wonder about the wisdom of charging in suggesting changes to VCL code in the face of "time limitations".

Comment: @MartynA you are right, I didn't say what version I'm using: it's XE5. I guess this hasn't changed in later versions?

Comment: Changing the RTL/VCL is always a terrible idea - it should never be the solution to any problem.  There are plenty of other ways to do what OP wants.

Comment: @MartynA Indeed, I forgot to ask about Delphi version, but proposed code modifications would work in any version (the only problematic thing in older versions like D7) would be type casting interface to `TWinControl`. Point is that modifications just have to be inserted before other code in `DoKeyDown`. I guessed that was quite obvious thing to do.

Comment: @J... I agree, changing VCL should never be first option. Sometimes there is just no other way, sometimes it is cleanest and fastest way to do things (if you don't have to change interface part and you don't use run-time packages)

Comment: @RodrigoGómez You should probably file feature request to Quality Portal. If it is not there, Embarcadero has no way of determining it is needed thing.