# Add keyboard events to TPaintBox component

Tags: delphi

I use a `TPaintBox` inside my application. Several mouse event handlers are already set up: mouse down, mouse up, etc. However, I also want to respond to keyboard input: if the user presses any function key, I would like to execute a separate procedure (event handler) and not the Mouse* event handler functions. But I also need the mouse position inside my new procedure.

How do I code this, as `TPaintBox` does not support any key press events?

```
procedure TForm1.PaintBox1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  //  here some code
end;

procedure TForm1.PaintBox1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
begin
  //  more code here
end;

procedure TForm1.PaintBox1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  // here other code
end;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`TPaintBox` does not descend from `TWinControl`, but rather from `TGraphicControl`, which means that it cannot receive input focus and so it has no functionality to react to keyboard events.

Possible solutions:

- Implement the `OnKeyPress` event of the parent form on which the PaintBox resides and enable the form's `KeyPreview` property.
- Add an action with the specific key press set as its `ShortCut` property and implement its `OnExecute` event handler. (See also: [When does a ShortCut fire?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27083261/757830)).
- Implement an `OnShortCut` event handler for the MainForm or the Application.
- Place and align the PaintBox on to a `TWinControl` and implement the `OnKeyPress` event of that container.

---

For combinations of mouse and keyboard input, check the `Shift` parameter of the mouse events or use the Win32 `GetKeyState()` and `GetKeyboardState()` functions.

Comment: I would vote for the last option, more specifically: put the paintbox on a frame. That way you can use the designer in the IDE and still reuse the frame on other forms in the project.