# Delphi TPopupMenu ShortCut Property in MDI application

Tags: forms, delphi, shortcut

I have a `TPopupMenu` with several buttons I would like to be activated via shortcuts. I have assigned them various shortcuts using the `ShortCut` property of the `TPopupMenu` class but they do not trigger the associated event when I use them. I seem to remember reading once that this functionality does not work for MDI applications - is this the case and, if so, what is the best way to overcome it?

Comment: [When does a shortcut fire?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27083261/757830)

Comment: Not sure it can solve, but have you tried using actions?